# Probability exercise in counting integers

Tags: probability

I'm working through some examples in a textbook on probability I bought just for some independent learning (Introduction to Probability with Statistical Applications; Geza Schay).

In the third chapter, the book offers a theorem to determine the size of a sample space by summing together arbitrary sets and subtracting their intersections, etc.

I am stuck on one example:

How many positive integers less than or equal to 1000 are there that are not divisible by 6, 7, and 8?
$$
S = \{1,2,...,1000\} \\
A = \{x \in S : (6 \mid x) \} \\
B = \{x \in S : (7 \mid x) \} \\
C = \{x \in S : (8 \mid x) \} \\
$$
Then,
$$
    |A| = \lfloor 1000 / 6\rfloor = 166 \\
    |B| = \lfloor 1000 / 7\rfloor = 142\\
    |C| = \lfloor 1000 / 8\rfloor = 125
$$
Then the author writes...

> $$
>     |A \cap B| = \lfloor1000 / 42\rfloor = 23 \quad (\text{obtained from multiplying $6\times7$?}) \\
>     |A \cap C| = \lfloor1000 / 24\rfloor = 41 \\  (\text{I can't see how this is obtained other than $(6\times8)/2$, but why?}) \\
>     |B \cap C| = \lfloor1000 / 56\rfloor = 17 \\
>     |A\cap B\cap C| = \lfloor1000 / 168\rfloor = 5
> $$

**How are we coming up with the denominators 24 and 168 for $|A \cap C|$ and $|A \cap B \cap C|$?**

Comment: To be divisible by $6$ and $8$ is the same as being divisible by $24$.  To be divisible by each of $6,7,8$ is the same as being divisible by $24\times 7=168$.

Comment: I think you are actually answering the question “How many positive integers less than or equal to 1000 are there that are not divisible by 6, 7, **or** 8?” There are $1000-\lfloor1000 / 168\rfloor=1000-5=995$ positive integers less than or equal to 1000 that are not divisible by 6, 7, **and** 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the denominator you need for the intersection is the least common multiple of the numbers creating the intersection, not their product.  For $6$ and $8$, that's $24$.  Any multiple of $24$ is also a multiple of $6$ and $8$.  For $6, 7,$ and $8$, that's $168$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will need to review this, but I understand now! Perfect